Power BI: Conditional calculate measure in filter
I'm trying to put a Conditional Calculate Measure in a filter. That's possible?
I want this in a filter:

"Consumo atual está acima da meta para ambos os indicadores."
"Consumo atual está acima da meta para um dos indicadores."
"Consumo atual está abaixo da meta para ambos os indicadores."
"Sem consumo no mês atual até o momento."

The measure has this structure:
IF(
    AND([Condição % Cons. Último Mês] = "Sim", [Condição % Cons. Último 6 Meses] = "Sim"), "Consumo atual está acima da meta para ambos os indicadores.",
    IF(
        AND([Condição % Cons. Último Mês] = "Sim", [Condição % Cons. Último 6 Meses] = "Não"), "Consumo atual está acima da meta para um dos indicadores.",
        IF(
            AND([Condição % Cons. Último Mês] = "Não", [Condição % Cons. Último 6 Meses] = "Sim"), "Consumo atual está acima da meta para um dos indicadores.",
            IF(
                AND([Condição % Cons. Último Mês] = "Não", [Condição % Cons. Último 6 Meses] = "Não"), "Consumo atual está abaixo da meta para ambos os indicadores.",
                IF(
                    AND([Condição % Cons. Último Mês] = "Sim", [Condição % Cons. Último 6 Meses] = "Vazio"), "Consumo atual está acima da meta para um dos indicadores.",
                    IF(
                        AND([Condição % Cons. Último Mês] = "Vazio", [Condição % Cons. Último 6 Meses] = "Sim"), "Consumo atual está acima da meta para um dos indicadores.", "Sem consumo no mês atual até o momento."
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)



ask your desired in English please or go to your regional stackoverflow website.

Is it possible to create a calculated column with this condition, and use it in a filter?
